# How to have a function return a value to a global variable (scope issue I think)?

Tags: c, scope, pow

I am trying to write a custom `pow` function that is compared to the actual result of `pow()`. I think I am having a scope issue, but I cannot figure out how to make my `MyPower` function return the result of my custom `pow` function to a global variable called '`result`'. I ultimately just need the number from `result` so that I can see if it is the same as what `pow()` got.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double base, pow_result, x , result;
int exponent, i;

double MyPower(double base, int exponent);
void DoTest(double base, int exponent);


int main(void){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < 5; j++){
            DoTest(i,j);
        }
    }
}


double MyPower(double base, int exponent){
    for(i = 1; i < exponent; i++){
        base *= base;
        result = base;
    }
    return result;
}


void DoTest(double base, int exponent){
    pow_result = pow(base, exponent);
    if(result == pow_result){
        printf("Testing %f to the %d power\n", base, exponent);
    }
    else{
        printf("%f to the %d is %f, result is %f\n", base, exponent, pow_result, result);
        printf("doesnt work\n");
    }
}
```

I am expecting result to be returned once it is the value of base to the correct power. Then it will be compared to pow_result and they will be equal. As of now, pow_result is returning the proper number, but result is just 0 every time. I am new to all this so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You never even call your `DoPower()` function... But as shown by your use of `pow()` you know how to assign a function's return value to a variable...

Comment: What do you mean by "return to a global variable"? That doesn't make sense. If you have a global variable just modify it from within the function, no need to return anything. Why you would even need a global variable in the first place is also an interesting question. This looks very much like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: The code shown doesn't define a variable `result` — anywhere.  You can't use it.  You should not return values from a function in a global variable — you should avoid global variables almost all the time.  You should call your function like you do the system-provided function, and save the result in a variable (you don't define `pow_result` either — you get more sympathy if your code compiles!).  So, you might use `double sys_pow = pow(base, exponent); double usr_pow = MyPower(base, exponent);` in `DoTest()`, and then you might be in with a fighting chance.  Note that `pow(4, 0) == 1`.

Comment: Try `static` methods; then the compiler will warn you that `MyPower` is not called.